# Php grab first image in page

Tags: php, image

Hey guys I'm wondering how I would be able to grab only the first image on a page. I want to echo it somewhere else possibly as a variable.

Comment: First, define what you mean as grab. Grab the URL from somewhere, of get the image data? As for the second bit, do you mean you want to display the image elsewhere? Or something else?

Comment: @Jon thanks for replying, I meant to grab the image data.

Answer (score 0):

well I have not attempted this before, but I found a website that looks like it gives a pretty good solution. if you are trying to copy the first image from a URL. http://phpsnips.com/snippet.php?id=61
hope that helps. :)

Comment: Link should explain better than my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You use PHP's DOMDocument class to grab the page's source, use an XPath query with DOMDocument to get the first img tag, then grab its src attribute.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

You can then use that to save the url, or download the file.